# trying to do a security motion sensor using the peizer and hc-sr04 but i am not able to find the errors the error code is all the way down

Tags: arduino-uno

```
#define trigPin 10
#define echoPin 9
#define buzzer 12
long duration;
int distance;



void setup() {​​
pinMode(trigPin,OUTPUT);
pinMode(echoPin,INPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(buzzer,OUTPUT);
}​​



 void loop() {​​
 digitalWrite(trigPin,LOW);
 delayMicroseconds(2);
 digitalWrite(trigPin,HIGH);
 delayMicroseconds(10);
 digitalWrite(trigPin,LOW);
 duration=pulseIn(echoPin,HIGH);
 distance=duration*0.034/2;
 Serial.print("DISTANCE=");
 Serial.println(distance);
 if (distance<=15){​​
 tone(buzzer,450);
 delay (500);
 noTone(buzzer);
 }​​
 else{​​
 noTone(buzzer);
 }
 ​​}
```

this is the error code

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows Store 1.8.42.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"


sketch_nov27a:9:15: error: stray '\342' in program

 void setup() {​​

               ^

sketch_nov27a:9:16: error: stray '\200' in program

 void setup() {​​

                ^

sketch_nov27a:9:17: error: stray '\213' in program

 void setup() {​​

                 ^

sketch_nov27a:9:18: error: stray '\342' in program

 void setup() {​​

                  ^

sketch_nov27a:9:19: error: stray '\200' in program

 void setup() {​​

                   ^

sketch_nov27a:9:20: error: stray '\213' in program

 void setup() {​​

                    ^

sketch_nov27a:14:2: error: stray '\342' in program

 }​​

  ^

sketch_nov27a:14:3: error: stray '\200' in program

 }​​

   ^

sketch_nov27a:14:4: error: stray '\213' in program

 }​​

    ^

sketch_nov27a:14:5: error: stray '\342' in program

 }​​

     ^

sketch_nov27a:14:6: error: stray '\200' in program

 }​​

      ^

sketch_nov27a:14:7: error: stray '\213' in program

 }​​

       ^

sketch_nov27a:18:14: error: stray '\342' in program

 void loop() {​​

              ^

sketch_nov27a:18:15: error: stray '\200' in program

 void loop() {​​

               ^

sketch_nov27a:18:16: error: stray '\213' in program

 void loop() {​​

                ^

sketch_nov27a:18:17: error: stray '\342' in program

 void loop() {​​

                 ^

sketch_nov27a:18:18: error: stray '\200' in program

 void loop() {​​

                  ^

sketch_nov27a:18:19: error: stray '\213' in program

 void loop() {​​

                   ^

sketch_nov27a:28:19: error: stray '\342' in program

 if (distance<=15){​​

                   ^

sketch_nov27a:28:20: error: stray '\200' in program

 if (distance<=15){​​

                    ^

sketch_nov27a:28:21: error: stray '\213' in program

 if (distance<=15){​​

                     ^

sketch_nov27a:28:22: error: stray '\342' in program

 if (distance<=15){​​

                      ^

sketch_nov27a:28:23: error: stray '\200' in program

 if (distance<=15){​​

                       ^

sketch_nov27a:28:24: error: stray '\213' in program

 if (distance<=15){​​

                        ^

sketch_nov27a:32:2: error: stray '\342' in program

 }​​

  ^

sketch_nov27a:32:3: error: stray '\200' in program

 }​​

   ^

sketch_nov27a:32:4: error: stray '\213' in program

 }​​

    ^

sketch_nov27a:32:5: error: stray '\342' in program

 }​​

     ^

sketch_nov27a:32:6: error: stray '\200' in program

 }​​

      ^

sketch_nov27a:32:7: error: stray '\213' in program

 }​​

       ^

sketch_nov27a:33:6: error: stray '\342' in program

 else{​​

      ^

sketch_nov27a:33:7: error: stray '\200' in program

 else{​​

       ^

sketch_nov27a:33:8: error: stray '\213' in program

 else{​​

        ^

sketch_nov27a:33:9: error: stray '\342' in program

 else{​​

         ^

sketch_nov27a:33:10: error: stray '\200' in program

 else{​​

          ^

sketch_nov27a:33:11: error: stray '\213' in program

 else{​​

           ^

sketch_nov27a:36:1: error: stray '\342' in program

 ​​}​​

 ^

sketch_nov27a:36:2: error: stray '\200' in program

 ​​}​​

  ^

sketch_nov27a:36:3: error: stray '\213' in program

 ​​}​​

   ^

sketch_nov27a:36:4: error: stray '\342' in program

 ​​}​​

    ^

sketch_nov27a:36:5: error: stray '\200' in program

 ​​}​​

     ^

sketch_nov27a:36:6: error: stray '\213' in program

 ​​}​​

      ^

sketch_nov27a:36:8: error: stray '\342' in program

 ​​}​​

        ^

sketch_nov27a:36:9: error: stray '\200' in program

 ​​}​​

         ^

sketch_nov27a:36:10: error: stray '\213' in program

 ​​}​​

          ^

sketch_nov27a:36:11: error: stray '\342' in program

 ​​}​​

           ^

sketch_nov27a:36:12: error: stray '\200' in program

 ​​}​​

            ^

sketch_nov27a:36:13: error: stray '\213' in program

 ​​}​​

             ^

exit status 1

stray '\342' in program



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice error there. I copied your code into my Arduino IDE and also got many errors with "stray X in program".

Then I looked at the file in the text editor vim and made all non-printable characters visible (that are characters, that cannot be seen, like control characters). Here is the result (as image, so that you can see the unprintable characters)

[image: Code listing in vim text editor]

As you see, you have some extra characters marked as `<200b>`. Google gives me the description for it as

> zero width space

so a space character, that has zero width and is thus not visible.

The compiler doesn't know, how to interpret these characters. I removed them and the compilation succeeded. Here again your code as text without the unprintable characters (and autoformatted to make it easier to read):

```
#define trigPin 10
#define echoPin 9
#define buzzer 12
long duration;
int distance;



void setup() {
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
}



void loop() {
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
  Serial.print("DISTANCE=");
  Serial.println(distance);
  if (distance <= 15) {
    tone(buzzer, 450);
    delay (500);
    noTone(buzzer);
  }
  else {
    noTone(buzzer);
  }
}
```

How these unprintable characters got into your code can only be guessed. Maybe you have copied parts of it from some website, which had these extra characters in it. Maybe you inserted them with some kind of text editor by accident.

---

For reference: The used FAQ section of vim with the commands to display non-printable characters [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimfaq.html#11.5):

> 11.5. How do I highlight all the non-printable characters in a file?
>
> You can use the following commands and search pattern to highlight all the
> non-printable characters in a file:
>
> :set hlsearch
> /(\p|$)@!.
>
> For more information, read
>
> :help /\p
>
> :help /bar
>
> :help /$
>
> :help /(
>
> :help /@!
>
> :help 'hlsearch'