# I tried to make a obstacle avoiding car (OAB), but my code seems to have a lot of errors

Tags: arduino-uno

```
#include <AFMotor.h>
#include <NewPing.h>
#include <Servo.h>



#define TRIG_PIN A0
#define ECHO_PIN A1
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200
#define MAX_SPEED 190
#define MAX_SPEED_OFFSET 20



NewPing sonar(TRIG_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE);



AF_DCMotor motor1(1, MOTOR12_1KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor2(2, MOTOR12_1KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor3(3, MOTOR34_1KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor4(4, MOTOR34_1KHZ);
Servo myservo;



boolean goesForward=false;
int distance = 100;
int speedSet = 0;



void setup() {​​​​



myservo.attach(10);
myservo.write(115);
delay(2000);
distance = readPing();
delay(100);
distance = readPing();
delay(100);
distance = readPing();
delay(100);
distance = readPing();
delay(100);
}​​​​



void loop() {​​​​
int distanceR = 0;
int distanceL = 0;
delay(40);

if(distance<=15)
{​​​​
moveStop();
delay(100);
moveBackward();
delay(300);
moveStop();
delay(200);
distanceR = lookRight();
delay(200);
distanceL = lookLeft();
delay(200);



if(distanceR>=distanceL)
{​​​​
turnRight();
moveStop();
}​​​​else
{​​​​
turnLeft();
moveStop();
}​​​​
}​​​​else
{​​​​
moveForward();
}​​​​
distance = readPing();
}​​​​



int lookRight()
{​​​​
myservo.write(50);
delay(500);
int distance = readPing();
delay(100);
myservo.write(115);
return distance;
}​​​​



int lookLeft()
{​​​​
myservo.write(170);
delay(500);
int distance = readPing();
delay(100);
myservo.write(115);
return distance;
delay(100);
}​​​​



int readPing() {​​​​
delay(70);
int cm = sonar.ping_cm();
if(cm==0)
{​​​​
cm = 250;
}​​​​
return cm;
} ​​​​



void moveStop() {​​​​
motor1.run(RELEASE);
motor2.run(RELEASE);
motor3.run(RELEASE);
motor4.run(RELEASE);
}​​​​

void moveForward() {​​​​



if(!goesForward)
{​​​​
goesForward=true;
motor1.run(FORWARD);
motor2.run(FORWARD);
motor3.run(FORWARD);
motor4.run(FORWARD);
for (speedSet = 0; speedSet < MAX_SPEED; speedSet +=2)
{​​​​
motor1.setSpeed(speedSet);
motor2.setSpeed(speedSet);
motor3.setSpeed(speedSet);
motor4.setSpeed(speedSet);
delay(5);
}​​​​
}​​​​
}​​​​



void moveBackward() {​​​​
goesForward=false;
motor1.run(BACKWARD);
motor2.run(BACKWARD);
motor3.run(BACKWARD);
motor4.run(BACKWARD);
for (speedSet = 0; speedSet < MAX_SPEED; speedSet +=2)
{​​​​
motor1.setSpeed(speedSet);
motor2.setSpeed(speedSet);
motor3.setSpeed(speedSet);
motor4.setSpeed(speedSet);
delay(5);
}​​​​
}​​​​



void turnRight() {​​​​
motor1.run(FORWARD);
motor2.run(FORWARD);
motor3.run(BACKWARD);
motor4.run(BACKWARD);
delay(500);
motor1.run(FORWARD);
motor2.run(FORWARD);
motor3.run(FORWARD);
motor4.run(FORWARD);
}​​​​

void turnLeft() {​​​​
motor1.run(BACKWARD);
motor2.run(BACKWARD);
motor3.run(FORWARD);
motor4.run(FORWARD);
delay(500);
motor1.run(FORWARD);
motor2.run(FORWARD);
motor3.run(FORWARD);
motor4.run(FORWARD);
}
```

These are the error messages:

```
    Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows Store 1.8.42.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

sketch_nov27b:44:15: error: stray '\342' in program

 void setup() {​​​​

               ^

sketch_nov27b:44:16: error: stray '\200' in program

 void setup() {​​​​

                ^

sketch_nov27b:44:17: error: stray '\213' in program

 void setup() {​​​​

                 ^

sketch_nov27b:44:18: error: stray '\342' in program

 void setup() {​​​​

                  ^

sketch_nov27b:44:19: error: stray '\200' in program

 void setup() {​​​​

                   ^

sketch_nov27b:44:20: error: stray '\213' in program

 void setup() {​​​​

     
[ trimmed ]
                       ^

sketch_nov27b:199:24: error: stray '\342' in program

 void turnLeft() {​​​​

                        ^

sketch_nov27b:199:25: error: stray '\200' in program

 void turnLeft() {​​​​

                         ^

sketch_nov27b:199:26: error: stray '\213' in program

 void turnLeft() {​​​​

                          ^

sketch_nov27b:199:27: error: stray '\342' in program

 void turnLeft() {​​​​

                           ^

sketch_nov27b:199:28: error: stray '\200' in program

 void turnLeft() {​​​​

                            ^

sketch_nov27b:199:29: error: stray '\213' in program

 void turnLeft() {​​​​

                             ^

Multiple libraries were found for "Servo.h"

 Used: C:\Users\amish\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Servo

 Not used: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\Servo

exit status 1

stray '\342' in program



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: You already asked about this sort of problem a few minutes ago. It's the same issue. Make sure you use a **text** editor for code or an IDE, nothing like Word. And be careful when you copy/paste from web pages.

Comment: could u pls recommend one

Comment: i am actually new to this so i have no idea of these text editors

Comment: Why do you ask essentially the same question again? You should really first look into, why you have those unprintable characters in the code? Have you just copied it somewhere? Then check that source.

Comment: For removing the unprintable characters, you can use Notepad++. Look for example (here)[https://www.shahabjafri.com/2020/03/01/how-to-find-non-ascii-unprintable-characters-using-notepad-plus-plus/] for a tutorial on how to find the unprintable characters (just found by googling). When you have removed them, you can again work in the Arduino IDE

Comment: Duplicate: [trying to do a security motion sensor using the peizer and hc-sr04 but i am not able to find the errors the error code is all the way down](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/79657/trying-to-do-a-security-motion-sensor-using-the-peizer-and-hc-sr04-but-i-am-not)

Answer (score 1):

You copied and pasted the code from a website that presents the code using typography, not code blocks.

You have lots of typographical special characters in your code from pasting it.

Instead of copying and pasting code you should read and understand code then *write your own*.